# Prevent horizontal scrolling on javascript modal open using css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, modal-dialog

my website is basically a horizontal scrolling website, i have a modal inside it, so when the modal is open, the user is able to scroll horizontally with the scroller button in mouse, i tried the following css to stop it but it doesnt work:

```css
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```

my modal javascript is like below:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModals");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtns");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closes")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

can anyone tell me how to accomplish this, thanks in advance

Comment: To apply the CSS rule, you've to add class "modal-open" to `body` when you're showing the modal.

Comment: @Teemu how, i didnt understand?

Comment: ?? This selector `body.modal-open` selects a body element with `modal-open` class. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList to add/remove a class to/from the body.

Comment: @Teemu can u please show an example

Comment: Just apply the linked docs to your case, there are plenty of [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#examples).

Comment: in your btn click to have modal 'block' add line which add your class modal-open to body: document.querySelector('body').classList.add('modal-open'). In the function which close the modal, add document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('modal-open'). That should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent horizontal scrolling on a JavaScript modal by adding the following CSS to your modal's container element:
overflow-x: hidden;

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}

html.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.modal {
    position: fixed;
}
```